# How can I copy-paste a directory from my computer to another computer using ssh?

Tags: macos, ssh, scp

Watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZtGJDvUlLYY) I have learned how to copy-paste from an external computer to my computer using ssh by doing

```
scp name@IPadress :/what/I/want/to/copyPaste
```

Now, my goal is to do the opposite, that is copying some content from my computer to some other computer using ssh. I have been trying to first ssh to this other computer and then ssh back to my computer but it doesn't work for some reason. So, **how can I copy-paste a directory from my computer to another computer using ssh?**

Note: I have Mac OSX Yosemite and am using the Terminal version 2.5.

Comment: To copy to other machine from your machine, copy the file and then connect to the other computer and paste it there .. like the below command 

scp /path/to/file username@remote_system:/path/to/destination

Comment: Can't you just connect via Mac OS X GUI to the given folder and transfer files to/from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using traditional Unix tools, man pages are a great help... have no fear to look at them!

Simplified extract from `man scp` :

`scp [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2`

So, your second argument, `:/what/I/want/to/copyPaste` was really: `me@myMac:/what/I/want/to/copyPaste`.

Now, you just have to change the order of the parameters to copy a local file to a remote computer, like this:

`scp me@myMac:/what/I/want/to/copyPaste name@IPadress:/remote/filepath`

or just:
`scp /what/I/want/to/copyPaste name@IPadress:/remote/filepath`

man pages FTW! Also, please take a look to `rsync` command. Very useful if you just want to update some changed files, and don't send again the other files.

Answer (score 1):

`scp` command **(secure copy)** is the best option to copy safely your files/directories to a remote host.

`scp` works with `ssh` service so you must consider to have your `ssh` service running so this could work.

The `scp` syntax is formed by the following way:

```
scp [options] [origin] [destination]
```

In this case, you want to do:

```
scp [options] [your-computer] [the-other-computer]
```

**Must know:** whatever you want to do (send or receive), the field where you refer to the "other computer" must have the following syntaxt:

```
[user]@[ipaddress/hostname][:/enitre/path/of/the/file-or-directory]
```

Now, you are attempting to copy an **entire** directory to the "other computer". `scp` command have a speciffic option to copy directories:

From `man scp`:

```
-r      Recursively copy entire directories.  Note that scp follows symbolic links encountered in the tree traversal.
```

So you must do:

```
scp -r /path/of-the/directory user@ipaddress:/path/where/you/want/to-copy
```